# Как сделать, чтобы при выделении текста мышкой он выделялся другим цветом?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при выделении текста мышкой он выделялся другим цветом? Не синим, а другим. Как, например, [тут](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua) - желтым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если как там, то нужно добавить в css эти стили:

```
::-moz-selection{
    background-color:#ffee38;
    color:#191919
}

::selection{
    background-color:#ffee38;
    color:#191919
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_selection